# Do devices that source power from the audio jack still work?

Tags: audio

Some of the early audio jack magnetic stripe readers had no battery.  (Think Square, although I don't know if theirs ever worked this way.)  They sourced all their power by rectifying the weak AC signal of a tone played out of the audio jack.

About a year ago, I either read somewhere or was told by a co-worker that unpowered MSRs will not work on a majority of newer (ICS+) devices.

**Edit**: Since it's apparently not obvious, every MSR that lacks a battery is going to have a certain minimum power requirement.  How much power you can source from the audio port is going to vary by device.  I would expect that Google has established a standard for the minimum amount of power you can source from an Android device's audio jack, much like there's a standard minimum amount of power you can source from USB.  I found [the audio headset spec](https://source.android.com/accessories/headset-spec.html), but I don't see anything in there about minimum power.

I'm finding multiple sources that say the iPhone 5 can source about 30mW from its audio jack, or 15mW per channel.  According to at least one source, [some Android devices can only source a small fraction of that](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7567/smartphone-audio-quality-testing/3).  So I'm trying to find out:

- if and when the minimum standard was lowered (or if there isn't a standard, if and when manufacturers started producing devices that could not source adequate power)
- whether this actually means that non-powered audio jack MSRs will not work on newer devices, or if that's just a rumor

Comment: If this worked before why wouldn't it now?  What is the proposed mechanism for headphones still working without there being a signal?

Comment: @MatthewRead See my edit.